# SQLite finding the previous record by a criteria in the SQL query

Tags: android, sqlite, date

I have to find the previous most recent record where it's BMI column isn't 0... 
For example, I'm opening an app screen where some data is entered. But if the BMI field is 0, I have to extract from the database the previous most recent record where that field isn't 0.

I tried this query, but it works only for the current month. If I give a date string which is in the next month, it isn't extracting anything.

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE strftime('%d.%m.%Y', `" + DATE_TIME + "`) < '"
            + date + "' AND " + BMI + " > 0";
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by comparing without the strftime. I used this query string:

```
"SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_DIARY + " WHERE (" + DATE_TIME + " < '"
            + formatter.format(dateCal.getTime()) + "') AND (" + BMI + " > 0)";
```

And formatted date by the SimpleDateFormatter.